# #1146 - Table 'crud_app.names' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrj9AohVhPA), crud app with node js and mysql.
My database, **crud_app** has a table named **crud_table**, and crud_table has got 3 columns, **id**, **names**, and **date_added**.

I am trying to make a SQL query using node js

```
async getAllData() {
        try {
            const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const query = "SELECT * FROM names"

                connection.query(query, (err, results) => {
                    if (err) { reject(new Error(err.message))}
                    resolve(results)
                }) 
            });
            
            console.log(response);
            return response;

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } 
    }
```

But I get this error

```
Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'crud_app.names' doesn't exist
```

And again I went to PHPMyAdmin to run this query in the console.

```
SELECT * FROM names
```

Output

[image: Output]

It is claiming that the **names** column does not exist but you can clearly see the column here

[image]

Is there any way I can resolve this problem?

Comment: In the youtube, see  at 21:45, Your column `names` is named `name` and also the table name `names` is shown.  But, for some reason, your table is named `crud_table`.

Comment: Oh, I did not notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Your table name is crud_table and within your table you have the column names. You cant select all the date from a column by using SELECT * on the column,with SELECT you select data from your table in your case crud_table,so if you want all the names then try this `"SELECT names FROM crud_table"`